# Can't forward packets between multiple RPi

Tags: networking, forwarding, static-routes

I have a home router with an Internet connection. I also have a computer which is in a place where I cannot connect it directly to the router. Hopefully, I have two raspberry pis that I didn't know what to do with.

[image]

I've run the following commands on PI #1 based on [@User1686](https://superuser.com/users/1686/user1686)'s answer:

```bash
    # Set static IP for eth0 interface
    ip addr add 192.168.1.100/24 dev ppp0
    
    # Set static IP for ppp0 interface
    ip addr add 192.168.0.1/24 dev ppp0

    # Enable IP forwarding
    echo 'net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1' >> /etc/sysctl.conf
    echo 'net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1' >> /etc/sysctl.conf
    sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf

    # Route packets to PI #2
    ip route add 192.168.2.0/24 via 192.168.0.2 dev ppp0

    # Masquerade all outgoing packets with his own IP
    iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

And run the following ones on PI #2:

```bash
    # Set static IP for eth0 interface
    ip addr add 192.168.2.1/24 dev eth0
    
    # Set static IP for ppp0 interface
    ip addr add 192.168.0.2/24 dev ppp0

    # Enable IP forwarding
    echo 'net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1' >> /etc/sysctl.conf
    echo 'net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1' >> /etc/sysctl.conf
    sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf

    # Forward packets to PI #1
    ip route add default via 192.168.0.1
    ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 via 192.168.0.1 dev ppp0

    # Masquerade all outgoing packets with his own IP
    iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

I've also enabled static IP on my computer to connect to PI #2:

```bash
    # Set static IP
    ip addr add 192.168.2.100/24 dev eth0

    # Forward packets to PI #2
    ip route add default via 192.168.2.1

    # Add DNS server
    echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" | sudo tee -a /etc/resolv.conf
```

I got some issues as I can't reach some IPs and the Internet from my computer.
Here is a quick table of what I've tried:

| Command | Pi #1 | Pi #2 | Computer | Any device on HomeRouter |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ping 192.168.0.1 | OK | OK | OK | NOPE |
| ping 192.168.0.2 | OK | OK | OK | NOPE |
| ping 192.168.1.1 | OK | OK | OK | OK |
| ping 192.168.2.1 | OK | OK | OK | NOPE |
| ping 192.168.1.100 | OK | OK | OK | OK |
| ping 192.168.2.100 | OK | OK | OK | NOPE |
| curl 8.8.8.8 | OK | OK | OK | OK |
| curl google.com | OK | OK | OK | OK |

Based on [@User1686](https://superuser.com/users/1686/user1686)'s answer, my computer is now able to talk to other devices on my home router but they are now able to communicate with my computer (`ping 192.168.2.100` for example).

Is there a way to route packets without editing the router configuration ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, every device needs a route for **every** network that's not local. It's not enough to just have a route towards a device – the device needs to have a route **back** to you as well.

In some situations it may already be covered by the "default" route (e.g. HomeRouter←Pi#2 is reachable via Pi#2's default route), but not in all cases.

1. The home router should have routes for both 192.168.0.0/24 and 192.168.2.0/24. Right now, it receives your pings from Pi#2 but is unable to respond (or rather, its responses go through the WAN link).

   (In both cases, the *nearest* router i.e. Pi#1 needs to be specified as the "gateway".)
2. Pi #1 needs a route for 192.168.2.0/24. You already have this.
3. Pi #2 needs a route for 199.168.1.0/24. You already have this, both as an explicit route and (probably) as default route.
4. Finally, the computer should just have a 'default' route via Pi #2 (that is, a 0.0.0.0/0 route). Right now it probably has no routes at all except for the subnet route.

If the home router doesn't support configuring static routes, you might be able to use SNAT as a workaround – make Pi#1 masquerade all packets with its own address, through iptables. However, keep in mind that masquerading only helps with connections established in **one direction only** (outbound); it will not help with sending "new" packets inbound.

So keep the use of SNAT/MASQUERADE to an absolute minimum and use normal routing wherever possible – e.g. if HomeRouter is the problem (can't do static routing), then only use SNAT on Pi#1, on the interface that's facing HomeRouter (i.e. on the edge of the routed network). You don't need the additional SNAT on Pi#2.

If you need to make inbound connections happen through the interface where you're forced to use SNAT, the typical workaround is to use DNAT (aka "port forwarding") – create a rule that matches certain connections to Pi#1 and DNATs them to the computer.

(It doesn't need to be port-by-port – you could also assign a whole 2nd IP address to Pi#1 and use it exclusively to DNAT literally everything for that address to the computer, kind of like the "DMZ" feature in routers.)

---

As you're already using `ip route`, I'd also recommend `ip addr add 192.168.2.100/24 dev eth0` instead of ifconfig. (The biggest problem that ifconfig still has (even in the latest version) is that it'll quietly fail to show multiple IPv4 addresses per interface, which can sometimes get very confusing.)

Comment: Hello @user1686, I've update my question with your answer. Masquerade did the job for outgoing packets but I can't add route to my home router. Is there a way to catch all packets on PI #1 interface and forward them to my computer ? Maybe should I set the same subnet (`192.168.1.0/24 ` for my computer) ?

Comment: No, the problem isn't about "catching" packets, the problem is that Pi#1 doesn't receive them in the first place – other devices on HomeRouter don't know that they should direct those packets towards the Pi; they direct all out-of-subnet packets towards HomeRouter. (No, you generally shouldn't use 192.168.1.0/24 there – you'd _still_ have two separate subnets, having them identically numbered would make them worse... Though it _could_ be done if you also used "proxy ARP", like already mentioned in the other thread where you tried to use the /32 routing, but that's just as much of a headache.)

Comment: Though, do you need to access the computer from other **PCs** only? (i.e. not smartphones or toasters?) If so, you could add the same route via Pi#1 on those PCs directly (without needing to reconfigure HomeRouter at all); e.g. on Windows you can do `route -p add`.

Comment: Finally, since NAT is already involved anyway, you could set up _port forwarding_ (DNAT) as a work-around – device from HomeRouter's network connects *to Pi#1* on some port, Pi#1 DNATs it to ThatComputer.